# Trouble with adding a rating bar in android studio app

Tags: android, rating

I add this rating bar to my app, but it my app crashes after the splash screen. I tried different version but it always crashes. Doesnt even get to the page with the rating bar.

What Am I doing wrong?

xml file:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:stepSize="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Value: " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff6600"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="Submit Rating"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RatingBar ratingBar;
    Button btn;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // Set ChangeListener to Rating Bar
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float rating=ratingBar.getRating();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


    public void openAppetizersList(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.appetizers){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppetizersActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

    public void openDishList(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.maindish){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DishActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

    public void openSidesList(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id.sides){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SidesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

    public void openDessertsList(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.desserts) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DessertsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

    public void openBonusButton(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.bonus) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BonusActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

    public void openTextClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.textClick) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BonusActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }



    }
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a crash log? That would make it a lot easier for us to find the issue :)

Comment: no...this is what I get:9:11:26 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
9:11:28 AM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 2s 4ms
9:12:54 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
9:12:55 AM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 940ms
9:13:30 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
9:13:33 AM Gradle build finished in 2s 983ms...it just says app keeps stopping

Comment: Ah, that's from the Android Studio event log. You can see debug information from your app in the [Android Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) when you're running the app in debug mode - a crash log should appear in there.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gbiondi.newactivity/com.example.gbiondi.newactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)

Comment: when I remove the rating bar code my apps runs fine...connects the all the pages etc..

Answer (score 0):

According to the crash log, you're trying to do `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` on a null object, meaning your `ratingBar` variable is null. Let's look at its declaration:

```
ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
```

However, in the layout XML, we see

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    ... />
```

Meaning there's a mismatch of the two ids ("ratingBar1" and "ratingBar"). You can fix this by changing either one of them to match the other. For instance, `ratingBar`:

```
ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
```

And in the XML:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    ... />
```

Comment: I changed that...it still is crashing

Comment: Mm is it the same crash though? Did you check the logs?

Comment: am I adding the code in the right spot. when I remove it all the app works, so it is something with this part. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: yes...                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gbiondi.newactivity/com.example.gbiondi.newactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar$OnRatingBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Oh, in that case I'm not quite sure what's happening. The XML sample you posted, is that from `activity_main.xml`? If not, that would be the issue - It needs to be the same as what you refer to in 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);'